# RewriteRule / RewriteCond simply not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Firstly I know there are a lot of similar questions on here and I can assure you that I have been looking through them. I've tried loads of variations using the answers here but after spending the entire morning trying to get this working I'm giving in and asking for help.

I've got the following Conditions and Rules in my .htaccess file but they simply aren't working:

```
# 301 --- http://www.example.com/ProjectSection.aspx?id=10 => http://example.com/projects/maintenance
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=10($|&)
RewriteRule ^ProjectSection\.aspx$ http://example.com/services/maintenance/? [L,R=302]

# 301 --- http://www.example.com/ProjectSection.aspx => http://example.com/projects
RewriteRule ^ProjectSection\.aspx$ http://example.com/projects? [L,R=302]
```

When I visit www.example.com/ProjectSection.aspx I get taken to a 404 page with the URL of http://example.com/ProjectSection.aspx. If anyone can help in the slightest I would be most grateful, I'm going bloody mad!!

Here is the full .htaccess file (it's a big en) and the code above is placed at the bottom.

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+) $1 [R=301,L] 

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] 

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svg|svgz|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

  # Audio
    AddType audio/mp4                                   m4a f4a f4b
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg

  # JavaScript
    # Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways):
    # http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
    AddType application/javascript                      js jsonp
    AddType application/json                            json

  # Video
    AddType video/mp4                                   mp4 m4v f4v f4p
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv

  # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot

    # Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types and sniff the content,
    # however, Chrome shows a warning if other MIME types are used for the
    # following fonts.
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf

    # Make SVGZ fonts work on iPad:
    # https://twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
    AddType     image/svg+xml                           svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip                                    svgz

  # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash               swf
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType application/xml                             atom rdf rss xml
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType image/x-icon                                ico
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache manifest
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc
    AddType text/x-vcard                                vcf

</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .webapp .xml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
  # RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "(^#.*#|\.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

  # Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

  # Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
```

I've stripped out a lot of comments and the other 301 rewrites however they all follow the same pattern, just with a different ID.

Any help would be amazing.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is buggy `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` try `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off` instead.

Comment: Just tried this but unfortunately it hasn't fixed anything. Thanks for pointing that out though.

I'm wondering if `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$` is necessary as that section you mention is doing that as well. Would it possibly cause problems? This whole .htaccess coding is a little alien to me.

Comment: Yes, the rule with redirect to non-www URL already there. But I can't see any rules for `/services/maintenance/` or `/projects`. Mean you rewrite from /projects to /ProjectSection.aspx as it is more logical?

Comment: The aim is to have it so that when someone visits http://www.example.com/ProjectSection.aspx?id=10 they get redirected to http://example.com/services/maintenance The first code segment of code I put up sits at the end of the 2nd set of code (should've been clearer about that).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this, although I'm still not sure if this is the correct way to do so but here is the code regardless:

```
# 301 --- http://www.example.com/ProjectSection.aspx?id=10 => http://example.com/projects/maintenance
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=10($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ProjectSection\.aspx$ http://example.com/services/maintenance/? [L,R=302]

# 301 --- http://www.example.com/ProjectSection.aspx => http://example.com/projects
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ProjectSection\.aspx http://example.com/projects? [L,R=302]
```

I've added, what I call, a catch all sign (is this what it is called?) in front of the ProjectSection part of the URL and this appears to have corrected it all.